# yarn dev loads forever

Tags: reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

I have a problem with yarn dev when I want to start localhost. When I first create a new next app using npx create-next-app and type in yarn dev, everything works fine, I start coding, server works. when I get out of vs code and come back, I get stuck on this screen [screen where I get stuck, yarn dev loads forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjIwt.png)

terminal works only if I type in CTRL + C, and I can't start localhost.

Comment: the problem is not in the code. when I, lets say, use npx create-next-app and have that setup, i can type in terminal yarn dev and it will compile and run in browser. however, if i dont touch and change anything and exit vs code, and then open it up again, and type "yarn dev" in terminal, it seems like it is compiling and i cant type anything in it except ctrl + c to terminate the process... i hope i explained it good... :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem many times just use CTRL+C to stop the server and restart it.